# Boto3 S3 Paginator not returning filtered results

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to list the items in my S3 bucket from the last few months. I'm able to get results from the normal paginator (`page_iterator`), but the `filtered_iterator` isn't yielding anything when I iterate over it.

I've been referencing the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html). I've double checked my filter string both using [JmesPath site](https://jmespath.org) and the AWS CLI, and it works in both places. I'm at a loss at this point on what I need to do.

Current Code:

```py
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
operation_parameters = {'Bucket': self.bucket_name,
                        'Prefix': file_path_prefix}
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?LastModified>='2022-10-31'][]")

for key_data in filtered_iterator:
    print('page2', key_data)
```

Comment: The [documented example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) seems to use backticks around the filtered value, not single quotes. Did you try that?

Comment: JMESPath doesn't support date comparison's by default.  You can force it down to a string comparison with something like `"Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"2022-10-31\"'][]"`

Comment: @AnonCoward it looks like that's what it was. Thanks!